# Problems wih make file code

Tags: makefile

When i run the code below , it give me an error message which is :

cc1: warning: main.c: not a directory [enabled by default]
frequent.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

```
CC = gcc 
CPPFLAGS = -I 

main: main.c headers.h  sortt.o frequent.o
    #$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@  
sortt.o:  headers.h sortt.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
frequent.o: headers.h frequent_word.c search_similar_word.o
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your rules.  Why is `frequent.o` listing `search_similar_word.o` as a prerequisite?  There's no reason that you can't build `frequent.o` before or at the same time as `search_similar_word.o`.

Also, you are using `$<` in the compilation line which expands to the first prerequisite, but the first prerequisite for `frequent.o` is `headers.h`, so you're trying to compile `headers.h` which is wrong: you want to compile `frequent_word.c`.

Ditto for `sortt.o`.

It's also very odd to name your object files with different names than the source files.

In your `CPPFLAGS` you're listing a `-I` flag but you've given it no argument: that flag takes a directory as an argument.

And finally, you are using the `-c` flag when you're trying to link the final object (I'm assuming the comment character `#` is just an artifact of debugging); that's not right as the `-c` flag tells the compiler to generate an object file, and to not link the final object.

Your makefile should look something like this:

```
CC = gcc 
CPPFLAGS = -I .

main: main.c headers.h  sortt.o frequent.o
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@  
sortt.o: sortt.c headers.h
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
frequent.o: frequent_word.c headers.h
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I have no idea what to do with `search_similar_word.o` since it doesn't seem to be used anywhere in your build.

Comment: THANKS alot ,and  this is first time i deal with make file , but for search_similar_word.o is a function used in freq , but these rules is a sub of my make file code  ...
i will follow you're guid line , and i will see , what if there are an error